# How do I run AWS Dead Letter Queue periodically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

### Requirement

I'd like to push DLQ messages to Lambda function periodically like cron.

### Situation

I created a batch processing system using SQS and Lambda.
So, I also prepare DLQ(Dead Letter Queue) to store the failed messages.

AWS proposed re-run failed messages in the DLQ with Lambda trigger.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-retries.html

I'd like to re-run periodically and automatically like cron, but AWS doesn't show how to do that except for manually.

In case I re-run manually, I **JUST** map the lambda and the DLQ. It's all done.
After that, I can re-run messaging dynamically with **Enable** and **Disable** button.

Otherwise, it's more complicated because no API switching Enable and Disable of Lambda trigger.
boto3 API: `create_event_source_mapping()` and `delete_event_source_mapping()` are seemed to better way.
But `delete_event_source_mapping()` requires **UUID** of the event mapping. I think it indicates that I need any datastore like **ElastiCache** or else.
However, I don't wanna prepare other resources in this situation if possible.

### My Solution

1. Cloud Watch Event call lambda.
2. lambda activate(Enable) **event source mapping** using `create_event_source_mapping()`.
3. lambda deactivate(Disable) **event source mapping** using `delete_event_source_mapping()`

It looks good to me at first, but in **3rd process** lambda want to know UUID from the 1st event. I think this case needs datastore including UUID.

Do you have any solutions without datastore?

Thanks.

Comment: You can configure scheduled trigger for lambda function. And in lambda function you need to write code to get messages from DLQ and process them.

Comment: Don't need `event source mapping` in your use-case. Just have your function use AWS SDK to get messages from the DLQ itself.

Comment: Please note that messages being stored in the Dead Letter Queue is normally an indication that "something went wrong". Merely reprocessing the messages does not guarantee they will work again. Therefore, you need a strategy on how to deal with messages that 'stay' in the queue.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You simplify my problem.
You guys means I call lambda from scheduled CloudWatch event at first, then the lambda just do polling the messages from the DLQ. That is it?

Comment: @SteaveStark Yes. It will need to have SQS permissions and use AWS SDK to get the messages from queue, and once processing completes, delete them from it.

Comment: Okay, I can see the way because of you.
So, I will put the solution for someone who have same problem after I did it.

Comment: @SteaveStark you should suggest that the person who solved the problem for you write that up as an answer. Rather than you personally writing the answer.